# Activemq error when launching servicemix command

Tags: activemq-classic, redhat, apache-servicemix

I have installed ServiceMix 3.3.2 on RedHat Linux Enterprise (RHEL). When I run `bin/servicemix` installer file after doing so many stuff it prompt me following error.

Any idea why its so?

```
 ERROR - ActiveMQEndpointWorker         - Connection to broker failed: Channel was inactive for too long:                
localhost/127.0.0.1:61616
javax.jms.JMSException: Channel was inactive for too long: localhost/127.0.0.1:61616
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1784)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1801)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:119)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.onException(InactivityMonitor.java:248)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor$4.run(InactivityMonitor.java:168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too long:  
localhost/127.0.0.1:61616
```

Comment: Are you sure its ServiceMix 3.3.2 as that is a very very old release, and its EOL and no longer supported / active maintained. The latest SMX release is 4.5.3.

Comment: Yes the thing I'm doing only support servicemix 3.3.* version. Can you please tell any pointers?